# labview DAQmx pwm getting results that jumps to 0 every few seconds

Tags: signal-processing, labview

I have the following code to read a pwm input(a dial). On a scope, this input is clean and constant. Here is the setup for the pwm input

[image]

Then, I read it like this:
[image]

However, reading this in labview I get this kind of result:
[image]

The output of the pwm is scaled from 0-1, and as you see, no matter where I am, the value always periodically jumps down to 0 and comes right back to where it was.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not expert at doing this kind of measurement but is it possible your code is occasionally trying to read the counter a second time before a new pulse has been counted, so it's getting a zero? Can you check for new data before reading and/or is there a timeout setting you should change?

Comment: Do you start and stop the task every time?